# How do I prevent a user from browsing my code on the server?

Tags: .htaccess, http, security

So, I recently made an API and now I'm trying to deploy it.

When I deploy it with FTP to the domain folder, it works as expected but there is a problem. I got this structure for example:

```
src/
|- user/
|- articles/
main.js
```

When I go to the file url like `https://mywebsite.api/main.js`, I can literally see the code contents of that file.

**How do I prevent this from happening? I just want to be able to execute HTTP requests to the endpoints. I don't want the user to be able to view files.**

Comment: You want to execute javascript on the server side? Really? If so, then you need a server doing that, certainly not an apache http server but maybe nodejs instead.

Comment: I am using nodejs @arkascha, I'm not that dumb lol

Comment: Using javascript on the server side is a bit exotic, though. Usually it is used on the client side, so inside a browser. For that the javascript file needs to be downloaded. How else should the client know about its content? But that means you publish your code which certainly means everyone can read it. That is true for _all_ web pages out there. Usually that is perfectly fine, why not? There are no secrets in such scripts (hopefully...). So what is _your_ issue with this?

Comment: @arkascha That people can view the code for example the authentication process, in which they know the exact flow and have an easier time finding bugs if they exist

Comment: Sorry, I did not want to suggest that you are dump! But if you know all about this, then how come you tagged this question with ".htaccess" which is an apache specific configuration file naming?

Comment: @arkascha We use Plesk, it has a NodeJS module, I upload files and start it and then the API works as expected. So if I include a htaccess I can block access to those files

Comment: OK, so the answer of my initial question is: yes, you do want to execute the javascript code on the server side.

Comment: @arkascha Don't you feel like it's really unprofessional to have a user be able to browse all your code if your software isn't open-source?

Comment: @arkascha yes I do, but I think I might need to have a non-apache server and run NodeJS with PM2 on that instead of uploading the files like this

Comment: Actually not at all. The OpenSource strategy has proven to result in more robust and therefore more secure code. So why not follow its principles?

Comment: Nevertheless I agree that if this code is meant to be used on the server side, then it should not be possible to download the code. I wonder why that is the case in the first place. That means that you actually offer _two_ endpoints to those files?

Comment: If your setup delivers the code instead of interpreting it then obviously your setup is wrong. I assume that it is your apache http server that delivers the code. So apparently your integration of NodeJS is not functional.